# Unable to connect to a FileMaker Server outside of local network

Tags: webserver, filemaker

**Intro**

I recently installed FileMaker Server 16 on a Mac Mini to host the databases I want to share.

I went through the installation process and the deployment without any hiccups. The port number stayed at the default 80.

**What works**

When I try to access the server via the local network, I have full access to the databases in WebDirect, with the local address: 192.168.1.149/fmi/webd.

**What doesn't work**

1. To allow access via internet, I have a No-IP account setup with dynamic checking of the external IP address of my router. The No-IP account is linked to my router, which has explicit options for this. I have already used this method for my FTP server, and it works well. So I do not think that the problem comes either from the router or the No-IP business.
2. The problem is when I try to access: http:// noiphostname.ddns.net:80/fmi/webd, on a computer outside of my local network, I invariably get an error message (Safari, Firefox and Chrome alike): "the server doesn't answer".

So I feel like I'm frustratingly close to a solution, but not quite there yet. I only have (very) limited experience with networks (the only thing I did in that regard was to setup the aforementionned FTP server…), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect by using the ip address to eliminate any DNS issues and verify that port 80 on the router is indeed routed to your server's internal address.

EDIT: use port 443 for WebDirect

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have port-forwarding set up on my router for port 80, which is redirected to the server internal address. When I try to use only the ip address, it still doesn't work. Maybe the problem is that I use the port 80, which can cause trouble because it's the default?

Comment: Try with port 443 https

Comment: Hallelujah god damn it. Thanks a huge lot. What do you think the problem was?

Comment: Webdirect is always served with https. It slipped my mind for a moment.